# UIScrollView paging selected in center

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiscrollview, pagination, center

I have made a UIScrollView which holds four UILabels. I would like that the selected UILabel is not the one in the left of the screen but in the center. I have attached two images to illustrate what I mean. On the first image, the green label would be the selected one and on the next image the blue label would be the selected one.

Is there any way to do this?

This is my code:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(428, 65)];
[scrollView setDelegate:self];

UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 107, 65)];
[label1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[label1 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[label1 setText:@"Wednesday"];
[scrollView addSubview:label1];
[label1 release];

UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(107, 0, 107, 65)];
[label2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[label2 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[label2 setText:@"Thursday"];
[scrollView addSubview:label2];
[label2 release];

UILabel *label3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(214, 0, 107, 65)];
[label3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[label3 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[label3 setText:@"Friday"];
[scrollView addSubview:label3];
[label3 release];

UILabel *label4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(321, 0, 107, 65)];
[label4 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[label4 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[label4 setText:@"Saturday"];
[scrollView addSubview:label4];
[label4 release];
```

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Comment: what do you mean by "selected"? Scrollview doesn't do selection, it just does scrolling.

Comment: That's right but I have enabled paging in the scrollview which makes it possible to give the illusion that a part of the scrollview is selected. But if there is any other way to do this, I would love to hear it. I have four UILabels and three of these needs to be visible on the screen at once. The one in the middle is the selected one.

Comment: The problem with UIScrollView's paging is that its contentSize defines its pages size, that means you can't have a full width contentSize and scroll by 1/3 of its width with the paging convenience...

Comment: Okay. It would have been great. Do you know any other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the easiest to rotate the UIPickerView. This can be done like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    arrayDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrayDays addObject:@"ONSDAG"];
    [arrayDays addObject:@"TORSDAG"];
    [arrayDays addObject:@"FREDAG"];
    [arrayDays addObject:@"LØRDAG"];

    arrayDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrayDates addObject:@"29. JUNI"];
    [arrayDates addObject:@"30. JUNI"];
    [arrayDates addObject:@"1. JULI"];
    [arrayDates addObject:@"2. JULI"];

    pickerViewDay = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [pickerViewDay setDelegate:self];
    [pickerViewDay setShowsSelectionIndicator:NO];
    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
    rotate = CGAffineTransformScale(rotate, 0.25, 2.0);
    [pickerViewDay setTransform:rotate];
    [pickerViewDay setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, (pickerViewDay.frame.size.height/2)-3)];
    [self.view addSubview:pickerViewDay];

    // Adding selection indicator to pickerview
    UIImage *selectorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DayPickerView_SelectionIndicator.png"];
    UIView *customSelector = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:selectorImage];
    [customSelector setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 74)];
    [customSelector setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, customSelector.frame.size.height/2)];
    [self.view addSubview:customSelector];
    [customSelector release];

    // Adding background to pickerview
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DayPickerView_Background.png"];
    UIView *custombackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
    [custombackground setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 74)];
    // [self.view addSubview:custombackground];
    [custombackground release];
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UIView *viewRow = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 80)];

    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14/2);
    rotate = CGAffineTransformScale(rotate, 0.25, 2.0);

    // Date
    CGRect rectDate = CGRectMake(30, 0, 150, 80);
    UILabel *date = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rectDate];
    [date setTransform:rotate];
    [date setText:[arrayDates objectAtIndex:row]];
    [date setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:37.0]];
    [date setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [date setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
    [date setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [date setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [date setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [viewRow addSubview:date];

    // Day
    CGRect rectDay = CGRectMake(-30, 0, 150, 80);
    UILabel *day = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rectDay];
    [day setTransform:rotate];
    [day setText:[arrayDays objectAtIndex:row]];
    [day setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:21.0]];
    [day setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.35 green:0.35 blue:0.35 alpha:1]];
    [day setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [day setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [day setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [viewRow addSubview:day];

    return viewRow;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [arrayDays objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [arrayDays count];
}
```

Comment: For styling the UIPickerView, visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744996/customizing-uipickerview-background-and-spacing