# Row Separator in UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios7, uipickerview

How do i hide the Separator in my Picker View.Here is the screenshot [image].

Here is the code for my custom UIPickerView.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

switch (component) {
    case 0:
        label.text=[_hourArray objectAtIndex:row];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MYRIADPRO-REGULAR" size:70];
        break;

    case 1:
        label.text=[_minutesArray objectAtIndex:row];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MYRIADPRO-REGULAR" size:70];
        break;

    case 2:
        label.text=[_ampmArray objectAtIndex:row];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MYRIADPRO-REGULAR" size:15];

        break;

    default:
        break;
}
return label;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 3;
}
```

Please Help me out.Thanks

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11451471/887325

Comment: Similar question was asked here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612279/uipickerview-how-to-hide-the-selection-indicator). Bimawa's link is useful. I tried that approach and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

To hide the selection indicator for a UIPickerView:

```
_pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = FALSE;
```

You can make it in code (as above) or in Interface Builder:

[image]

**Edit**

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPickerView/showsSelectionIndicator):

> On iOS 7 and later you cannot customzie the picker view’s selection
>   indicator. The selection indicator is always shown, so setting this
>   property to NO has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 5 you can use this workaround. Just add this code to your viewcontroller class:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    for i in 1...2 {
        myPickerView.subviews[i].isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you really need, here is a pragmatic solution: Create a subclass of `UIPickerView` where you override `didAddSubview`. If the added subview has a height <= 1.0, then it's a separator and you can hide and/or remove it.

NOTE: Might break in future iOS versions, so handle with care.