# IOS7 UIPickerView how to hide the selection indicator

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, uipickerview

How can I hide those 2 lines on the selected row?

[image]

Comment: The lines are by-design. I'd be very surprised if you could remove them.

Answer (score 37):

```
[[pickerview.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setHidden:TRUE];
[[pickerview.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setHidden:TRUE];
```

Use this in `titleForRow` or `viewForRow` delegate method of the `pickerView`.

Answer (score 25):

Based on the other answers, I decided to enumerate the subviews and saw that the lines have a height of `0.5` so my solution now looks like this in Swift:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

     pickerView.subviews.forEach({

          $0.hidden = $0.frame.height < 1.0
     })

     return myRowCount
}
```

And in Objective-C

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

     [pickerView.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *subview, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        subview.hidden = (CGRectGetHeight(subview.frame) < 1.0) 
     }];

    return myRowCount
}
```

Obviously not particularly future proof, but probably more so than hiding a subview at a given index.

**Edit:** Updated to handle the case provided by @Loris

Comment: BTW, if you added some subview to a UIPickerView which also has a height of 0.5, you can use `.tag` for this subview in order to identify it and prevent from hiding

Comment: On iPhone 7 + the height of the line is 2/3 (0.666666666666667) instead of 0.5, so I ended up checking if the height was less than 1. 

`func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

     pickerView.subviews.forEach({

          $0.hidden = $0.frame.height <= 1
     })

     return myRowCount
}`

Answer (score 11):

In iOS7 setting the parameter pickerview.showsSelectionIndicator has no effect, according to the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPickerView.html).

However, as a UIPickerView in the end is a UIView with subviews, I checked what subviews there were. I found 3, the first one contained all the components of the UIPickerView, and the other two are the two lines.

So by setting the second and third (index 1 and 2) hidden, the two lines were removed.

```
[[pickerview.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setHidden:TRUE];
[[pickerview.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setHidden:TRUE];
```

It's not a real nice solution, and definitely not forward compatible, but for now it gets the job done. Hope this helps.

Comment: By the way. When you remove these lines, the look is kindof weird, because the 3d effect of the roll changes the position of the views. I was playing around and you can also change the color of these lines like this:  `((UIView *)[self.subviews objectAtIndex:1]).backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    ((UIView *)[self.subviews objectAtIndex:2]).backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

Comment: thank for your answer but it thrown a NSRangeException -> 
-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: I've added 2 views to hide these lines but it's very ugly, have no choice for now

Comment: I just rechecked. I actually subclassed the UIPickerview and added these lines in the initWithFrame method (so referenced self.subviews). Perhaps the pickerview was not initialized yet in your code at the point where you added the setHidden lines?

Comment: Maybe you can share some code? I am interested if this solution would break easily in other situations.

Comment: @James03 changing the color of selector lines works. If you don't subclass the UIPickerView, you should call the code from -viewDidLayoutSubviews, it won't work from -viewDidLoad

Comment: morksinaanab's comment is what worked for me and my webview picker. Thank You :)

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me in Swift in iOS 9 Beta.

```
datePicker.subviews[0].subviews[1].hidden = true
datePicker.subviews[0].subviews[2].hidden = true
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3 Version (Working):

```
pickerView.subviews[1].isHidden = true
pickerView.subviews[2].isHidden = true
```

Comment: worked for me, put it in viewDidLoad function. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        pickerView.subviews.forEach({
            $0.isHidden = $0.frame.height < 1.0
        })
        return 1
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

It is working before ios7.

```
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = NO;
```

for more info in ios7 see this doc

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPickerView.html

Comment: yes already tried, on ios7 apple's doc says that it cannot be hidden, I'm looking for a trick, is there a proper way to hide indicators ?

Comment: There is no technical way right now. If you wanna then its on you make it according to your logic.

Comment: @James03 , i believe found a way to remove the lines, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is easily achieved. Just place your PickerView inside a ScrollView with the desired size of your row, and use the picker delegate(pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:) method to change the the row height of the picker to a little bigger than your ScrollView. Like that, the lines will be hidden.

Comment: i like this method. it's easy for a user to see what to do, without taking up too much screen space..

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4.2**

Paste both lines of code into either your titleForRow or viewForRow delegate method of the pickerView.

```
pickerView.subviews[1].isHidden = true
pickerView.subviews[2].isHidden = true
```

And you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by a simple trick:
Place picker view in a view, and set clip subviews property of this view = true.
Now, just set height of row in picker view = height of container view then the line will disappear.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) ->  String? {
        pickerView.subviews[1].isHidden = true
        pickerView.subviews[2].isHidden = true
        return pickerData[row]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I opted for a different approach to make it a bit more future proof just in case Apple decide to change something down the line

```
for subview in setPickerView.subviews{
    if subview.frame.origin.y != 0{
        subview.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

since the (subView that contains the items)'s origin y location is 0 then I can safely hide anything else without risking an index out of bounds error

Enjoy

EDIT: I forgot to tell you that I put it in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method!

Comment: This works also in - func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {}

Answer (score 0):

Just write this code in your viewdidload method

```
[[PickerView.subviews objectAtIndex:1] setHidden:TRUE];
[[PickerView.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setHidden:TRUE];
```

Comment: I have a feeling this only worked in your viewDidLoad because the pickerView was totally defined.  I had to use ChrisH's answer above for Swift to hide the lines.  I'm not sure why Apple has a setting and they ignore it.

Comment: Yes If you use interface builder then you get the pickerview. otherwise you have to set this after programatically created the picker

Answer (score 0):

In ios7 we can't hidden the separate line in UIPickerView 
and we can know that from this page:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/showsSelectionIndicator

But we can add two UIViews to cover it and the width of two UIViews is 1.
Some sample code here:

```
s_leftLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(s_pickerView.frame.size.height/2,
                                                      s_pickerView.frame.size.width/2 - kWidthOfPickerPage/2 + 1,
                                                      1,
                                                      s_pickerView.frame.size.height)];
s_leftLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
s_leftLine.layer.zPosition = s_pickerView.layer.zPosition + 1; // make sure the line is on the top
[s_pickerView addSubview:s_leftLine];
```

Ok, this will be much better :]
if someone has better answer just write it down for sharing :)

Answer (score -1):

This code works fine for **iOS 10 with swift 3**

Just add this code in your view controller class.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        timePickerView.subviews[1].isHidden = true
        timePickerView.subviews[2].isHidden = true
        }
```

Comment: Should't hard-code index offsets. Could crash is iOS changes.

Answer (score -3):

You can also make an extension to UIPickerView:

```
extension UIPickerView {
    func hideSelectionIndicator() {
        for i in [1, 2] {
            self.subviews[i].isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

And then just call `myPickerView.hideSelectionIndicator()` for each PickerView you want to alter.

Comment: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException, reason: -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]` in 2018

Comment: Shouldn't hard-code index offsets. (Possible crash)