# swift picker view hide selection indicator

Tags: swift2, ios9, uipickerview

i wanna to hide selection lines in picker view 
i tried this in

```
datePicker.subviews[0].subviews[1].hidden = true
datePicker.subviews[0].subviews[2].hidden = true
```

in this method

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    weightPicker.subviews[0].subviews[1].hidden = true
    weightPicker.subviews[0].subviews[2].hidden = true
    return weightNumber[row] as! String
}
```

but it has no effect. And if i put this in view did load app will crash

Comment: What's the reason of hiding selection line in picker view?

Comment: well....its ugly + my boss don't want it there.

Comment: Ok, boss is boss :) Did you try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/22011641/4250188? In your case you're calling one more extra "subviews" call. Probably that's the reason you're getting the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in **viewDidLayoutSubviews()** method.

**Objective-C**

```
pickerView.subview[1].backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

pickerView.subview[2].backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
pickerView.subviews[1].isHidden = true

pickerView.subviews[2].isHidden = true
```

Comment: `subviews` returns 0 elements